# Buttons on my Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, operating-systems, gui, eclipse

All of my buttons on any kind of popup window don't seem to work that great with my mouse, I sometimes have to press enter on my keyboard after clicking, I hear that there is a fix for this out there somewhere, anyone know where I can find this? I am using GNOME.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Eclipse buttons. I'd like to know how I can get rid of this annoying bug too!

Comment: Yes this is an issue with Eclipse!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug with more than eclipse. This is a GTK bug that also affects some flash objects and programs like eclipse. It's driving me nuts and the only way to fix it at the moment is to downgrade GTK to a previous version which is not something I'm willing to do.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291257

You can also set

```
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
```

[before launching eclipse](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/442078) to fix it. There is a post [here](http://mou.me.uk/2009/10/31/fixing-eclipse-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/) that covers what you need to do. It's really not that hard to fix until the GTK team gets this fixed.

According to the [eclipse bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287307), this issue should be fixed in Eclipse 3.5.2

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. It is indeed an issue with Eclipse, with a massive [bug report page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/443004) to go along with it.

If you check out the last few comments, it appears it has been fixed in the Ubuntu Eclipse package (check Synaptic), but not in the official release on the Eclipse website. Try installing the build from Synaptic and see how that goes :)

Comment: I'll try this out John, lets see if it works!